# Detecting whole words using str_detect() in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have a string in R:

```
c("FLT1", "FLT1P1", "FLT1-FLT2", "SGY-FLT1, GPD")
```

I want to keep all matches that have FLT1 but not when other *alphanumeric* characters are added.  In other words, I want to keep all entries except the second one, as all of them mention FLT1, but the second one mentions FLT1P1.

When I use str_detect, it returns everything as true:

```
str_detect(string, "FLT1")
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Can anyone advise on the best method to only return the items that mention FLT1?

Comment: you can anchor your regex

Comment: Don't use regex for full-string exact matches. `string == "FLT1"`

Comment: If I use string == "FLT1" it misses out entries such as "FLT1-FLT2"

Comment: Okay, so when you way *"but not when other characters are added"*, it seems you don't include `"-"` in your definition of character. Do you mean "but not when other letters" are added? "...not other letters and numbers"? "Anything but "-"? Something else?

Comment: you can try `str_detect(string, "FLT1(\\W|$)")`, specifying no alphanum characters (i.e. a character that is not alphanumeric or the end of string) after FLT1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Probably* word boundaries with `\\b` will work. They match the beginning or end of strings and the transition to/from any character that is not a number, letter, or underscore.

```
str_detect(string, "\\bFLT1\\b")
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

"No other characters added" means to me word boundary which is expressed by `\\b`.

```
x <- c("FLT1", "FLT1P1", "FLT1-FLT2", "SGY-FLT1, GPD")
stringr::str_detect(x, "FLT1\\b")
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Or base R:

```
grepl("FLT1\\b", x)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is by using `\\b`, as noted by others.
Alternatively you can use positive lookahead:

Data:

```
x <- c("FLT1", "FLT1P1", "FLT1-FLT2", "SGY-FLT1, GPD")
```

Solution:

```
grep("FLT1(?=$|-|,)", x, perl = T, value = T)
[1] "FLT1"          "FLT1-FLT2"     "SGY-FLT1, GPD"
```

Here, `grep`matches `FLT1` **if**, and only if, the immediately next thing is either the end of the string (`$`) or `-` or `,`. By implication, it does not match when the immediately next char is, for example, alphanumeric.

Or, if the rule is that you want to exclude values where alphanumeric characters are added, you can use **negative** lookahead:

```
grep("FLT1(?!\\w)", x, perl = T, value = T)
[1] "FLT1"          "FLT1-FLT2"     "SGY-FLT1, GPD"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use look arounds

```r
library(stringr)

x <- c("FLT1", "FLT1P1", "FLT1-FLT2", "SGY-FLT1, GPD","AFLT1")

x %>% 
  str_detect("(?<![:alpha:])FLT1(?![:alpha:])")
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>